# DataGrid ComboBox open with one click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a data grid with five columns. Column 1, 2 and 3 are TextColumns where the user can type in. Column 4 and 5 are ComboBoxes:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myTable" DataGridCell.Selected="grd_Cells_Selected" SelectionUnit="Cell"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment ="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding mySourceCollection}">

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate1" DataType="vm:GridItem" >
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding something, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding sometging}" DisplayMemberPath="desc"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate2" DataType="vm:GridItem">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboMY" SelectedValue="{Binding something, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="desc" ItemsSource="{Binding something}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="H1" Binding="{Binding h1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="H2" Binding="{Binding h2}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="H3" Binding="{Binding h3}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combo1" CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate1}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate1}"  />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combo2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate2}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate2}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

 </DataGrid>
```

I use

> DataGridCell.Selected="grd_Cells_Selected"

with following CodeBehind to make the cells selected by only one click:

```
private void grd_Cells_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell)) {
        // Starts the Edit on the row;
        DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
        grd.BeginEdit(e);
    }
}
```

This does not work for the ComboBoxes. I have to click twice to open the ComboBox. Is there a way to open the ComboBox with only one click into the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround. Not pretty but it works so far:

I extended the grd_Cells_Selected() by getting the current column i clicked in:

```
int col = PNTable.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
```

Now i only say grd.BeginEdit(e) if the current column is one of the DataDridTerxtColumns

The whole code so far:

```
private void grd_Cells_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    int col = PNTable.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
    if (col <= 2) {
        if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell)) {
            // Starts the Edit on the row;
            DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
            grd.BeginEdit(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If someone has a smarter solution i would be happy

Answer (score 0):

Change the "EditMode" property of your DataGridView control to "EditOnEnter". This will affect all columns though.

Comment: Dont get it. I dont use the DataGridView Tag and there is no option du use EditMode in my XAML